# Call State Always : "ERROR_USER_UNAVAILABLE" Linphone manager Android

Tags: android, state, phone-call, linphone

I want to make application that can call with using Linphone library, but why when I want to call a number (this number can be called using usual phone apps), it always state : "ERROR_USER_UNAVAILABLE"

```
private void call(String ticket_id) {
    updateState("CALLING");
    Log.d(TAG_CALL, "try to call");
    LinphoneManager.getInstance().newOutgoingCall(msisdn, ticket_id);
    callingAttemptHandler.postDelayed(callingAttempt, 1000 * 30);
}

@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(LinphoneCall call, State state, String message) {
    Log.d(TAG_CALL, "state: " + state.toString() + " value: " + state.value());
    Log.d(TAG_CALL, "message: " + message);

    int stateValue = state.value();
    switch (stateValue) {
    case 1:// incoming received
            // startActivity(new Intent(this, IncomingCallActivity.class));
        startActivity(new Intent(this, WhenIncomingActivity.class));
        break;

    case 2:// outgoing init
        break;

    case 3:// outgoing progress
        break;

    case 4:// outgoing ringing
        break;

    case 5:// outgoing early
        break;

    case 6:// connected
        break;

    case 7:// connected streaming
        break;

    case 8:// pausing
        break;

    case 9:// paused
        break;

    case 10:// resuming
        break;

    case 12:// error: User not found, User is temporary unavailable, Request
            // timeout
        if (CallResponse.ERROR_BUSY.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.call_error_user_busy), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else if (CallResponse.ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.error_incompatible_media), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else if (CallResponse.ERROR_NOT_FOUND.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.call_error_user_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else if (CallResponse.ERROR_USER_UNAVAILABLE.equalsIgnoreCase(message)
                || CallResponse.ERROR_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.call_error_user_unavailable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        } else {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.call_error_user_unavailable), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        break;

    case 13:// call end: Call Ended, Call Declined, Call Terminated
        if (CallResponse.CALL_DECLINED.equalsIgnoreCase(message)) {
            displayCustomToast(getString(R.string.call_end_declined), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        break;

    case 15:// updated by remote

        break;

    case 18:// call released
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Anybody have the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking to provider, the provider tell me that the phone number is not active any more.

So response state CallResponse.ERROR_NOT_FOUND or CallResponse.ERROR_NOT_FOUND can be caused by the number that used is not active anymore.